# How to send a SQL Server Report as Word doc to BPOS SharePoint document library

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I'm trying to determine how exactly to convert SSRS reports to Word docs and have them sent to the Sharepoint doc library. From my research, all I could gather was that it's all part of SS Integration Services, but little else. I'm not using report builder, but Visual Studio.

Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you would like to do is have the report run, and the results be exported to a file location?

If so, its not too difficult.  I used this as a starting point:

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/10/29/exporting-a-sql-server-reporting-services-2005-report-directly-to-pdf-or-excel.aspx

I was able to create a simple WinForms app that upon a button click would run a report and save the results as a PDF to a file location.

I am not familiar with the Sharepoint doc library.  So I'm not sure if you export the results as Word doc to the file location which holds the documents if it will auto-magically show up in the list.

Comment: Mmmm, let me try to be more specific:

Comment: So SSRS has a data-driven subscription that I am using to copy docs into a folder. This DDS allows me to save docs as Word. They need to be word because I need to be able to edit these docs. SSIS needs to pick these up from that folder and input them into the Sharepoint Doc Library.  What's the quickest and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: If im understanding correctly, I would just create a simple SSIS package that maybe utilized a script task to copy the files from their saved location into the Doc Library.  What I am unsure of is if Sharepoint will automatically display those files in the menu just because they are in the folder.  Im not sure if one has to manually add the files to Sharepoint so the end user can select/display them.  If so, I would think there would be a way to progmatically add the file, possibly also via an SSIS script task.